# How to replace a string if double condition matches

Tags: sed

There is a command to replace `bbb` to `ccc`, if the line contains `abc`.

```
echo "abc yyy bbb xzy" | sed -e "/abc/ s/bbb/ccc/"
```

Does anyone know what the command would be, if I want to do the replacement, only if the line contains both `abc` and `xyz`?

Comment: For your specific sample it will be `sed '/^abc.*xyz$/{s/bbb/ccc/}'`

Comment: Or if you prefer nested condition `sed '/abc/{/xyz/{s/bbb/ccc/}}'`.

Comment: 2nd one preferred: will match `xyz abc bbb` -- the 1st won't

Answer (score 2):

Because it doesn't matter which one is matched first, you can look for `abc` first, then make the substitution if also `xyz` matches<sup>1</sup>:

```
sed '/abc/{/xyz/s/bbb/ccc/}'
```

or, considerably less elegant:

```
sed '/abc.*xyz\|xyz.*abc/s/bbb/ccc/'
```

but no nesting.

<sup>1</sup>BSD sed requires a semicolon before the closing brace.

Comment: GNU `sed` will be happy with what you wrote; BSD `sed` (found on Mac OS X, for example) requires a semicolon after the final `/` before the `}`.  It's funny like that — though I think it is consistent with the POSIX specification.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I checked the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html): it shows using newlines and mentions that "Historically, the sed `!` and `}` editing commands did not permit multiple commands on a single line using a <semicolon> as a command delimiter. Implementations are permitted, but not required, to support this extension." And BSD sed seems to interpret that as "semicolon required before closing brace...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Aside: how did you make an emdash in comments? `&endash;` and `&emdash;` don't work for me.

Comment: It's certainly something along those lines.  It's a minor difference which catches people who mainly use GNU `sed` when they port to Mac or BSD.  GNU `sed` is happy with what you wrote, and that covers most people.  I forget what Solaris, HP-UX, AIX expect — it's an area to be cautious about.

Comment: Option-Shift-Underscore on a Mac keyboard — it generates an em-dash; using Option-Minus generates – an en-dash.  Copy and paste from a convenient em-dash or en-dash in the text on the page also works.  One other advantage; it only uses 1 character of the 600 you're allowed, whereas `&mdash;` uses 7.

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk and you can code it as you'd write it, with `&&` between the conditions:

```
awk '/abc/ && /xyz/ { sub(/bbb/,"ccc") } 1'
```

Try writing:

```
awk '(/abc/ && /xyz/) || (/def/ && (/ghi/ || /klm/)) { sub(/bbb/,"ccc") } 1'
```

or any other more interesting compound condition with sed. Awk is available everywhere sed is and the above is fully portable and will work as-is in every awk in every UNIX installation.